# Woocommerce webhook debugging on nginx in a docker container

Tags: wordpress, nginx, docker, woocommerce, docker-compose

I just moved a woocommerce shop from a normal shared hosting to a setup with docker containers and docker-compose. Actually it is running on nginx and it works fine so far. The only thing which stopped working are the webhooks.

If I go to the webhooks settings and configure e.g. order complete hook and save this settings the URL gets called without any problem and I can see the test call from the webhook save. But when I actually complete an order (yes I also tried it with lot of other hooks) just nothing happens. I have debugging and error logging to true and I still can't see any errors. Also in the server error logs are no errors.

Do I need some special settings or services for webhooks to work properly with nginx? Do you have a quick idea how I can debug this issue here, if I get no errors with debug true and error log all? Or maybe are there any issues regarding file permissions? (already set 644 and 755 properly)

Specs:

- Wordpress 4.6.1
- Woocommerce 2.6.4
- nginx 1.11.4
- PHP 7.0.11
- cUrl 7.38.0, OpenSSL/1.0.1t
- MySql 5.7.15
- Docker 1.12.1
- Docker Compose 1.8.0

Answer (score 1):

Is your `try_files` section of your Nginx config stripping query strings from `index.php?` The cart requires query strings.

If you have a line like:

```
location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}
```

Try:

```
location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
```

Restart Nginx after a change like that.

**And, to dump all actions and filters, check out** https://gist.github.com/studiograsshopper/1273784

Use this is the theme's `functions.php` file.

```
add_action( 'all', create_function( '', 'var_dump( current_filter() );' ) );
```

Comment: thx for the quick reply. Yes indeed, I already did this and in my config file is exaclty the second example. Are there no way to debug these anoying webhooks?

Comment: Added a function to try, though I have never used it myself.

Comment: Thanks again @markratledge. I had a little bit more in depth research with xDebug and now Im getting closer to a solution. The main problem is in this function wp_schedule_single_event( time(), 'woocommerce_deliver_webhook_async', array( $this->id, $arg ) );

It tries to schedule an webhook delivery but it never delivers it. Im actually not quite sure why it is not triggering the delivery function. If I call it directly there (so $this->deliver( $arg );) it works perfectly and it makes the webhook call like it should. Could this be an issue with CRON and nginx there?

Comment: Don't know; I'd look at https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_schedule_single_event/ and be sure you have the necessry parameters in ithe function so it runs, and then see if the cron issues are still there.